# EDITED: My GridView Gallery load images too slowly

Tags: android, image, gridview

Hello kindhearted experts.

I am a newbie to Android Programming world.

I've asked a question about how to list images of phone on a GridView with three columns.

I finally got to the part where I am able to show my images on a GridView, but I am thinking my decoding method isn't efficient enough that it says "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." and it is obvious the application is really slow.

here is my part of my code:

```
        BitmapFactory.Options bo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bo.inSampleSize = 8;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbsDataList.get(position), bo);
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 95, 95, true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(resized);
```

Also, if this part helps you to figure out the issue:

```
        private void getThumbInfo(ArrayList<String> thumbsIDs, ArrayList<String> thumbsDatas){
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE};

        Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                proj, null, null, null);

        if (imageCursor != null && imageCursor.moveToFirst()){
            String thumbsID;
            String thumbsImageID;
            String thumbsData;

            int thumbsIDCol = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int thumbsDataCol = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            int thumbsImageIDCol = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int num = 0;

            do {
                thumbsID = imageCursor.getString(thumbsIDCol);
                thumbsData = imageCursor.getString(thumbsDataCol);
                thumbsImageID = imageCursor.getString(thumbsImageIDCol);
                num++;
                if (thumbsImageID != null){
                    thumbsIDs.add(thumbsID);
                    thumbsDatas.add(thumbsData);
                }
            }while (imageCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        imageCursor.close();
        return;
    }
```

If anyone could give me an idea to fix this lag, I will appreciate it very much.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: nice tutorial here -- http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: Hello @Tasos thank you for your reply. As I am seeing that tutorial, I still can't seem to locate the photos inside of the phone. That tutorial is looking into an external sd card itself. Could you help me about how I should locate the photos in the gallery of the phone itself? Thanks in advance

Comment: if you go to the comments you find  solutions there --in manifest add (<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>) to get access for internal storage  -- and add the the Pictures folder (public static final String PHOTO_ALBUM = "DCIM/Camera";)

Comment: scrap this   -- (<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>) -- according to  this -- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html -- Your application always has permission to read and write files in its internal storage directory.

Comment: @Tasos Thanks for your help. I was able to get through reading the images on the gallery itself and as you could see, I edited the post itself. If you could give me any idea about the new post, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: read this on "Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread" -- http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html -- plenty of examples on the net also on how to use bitmap decoding using AsyncTask  -- you can also use Picasso for ease of use --- http://square.github.io/picasso/